# How to find the equation of a line of which a diameter is on with one given endpoint? Is it possible?

Tags: circles

E.g., $A(0,2)$ lies on Circle $C$: $x^2+y^2+3x+4y-12=0$. Line $L$ passes through $A$ and divides the circle into two equal halves. Find the equation of $L$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you drawn a diagram? Please show some of your thoughts here and more people will be willing to help you out

Comment: [This site](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Circles/Circles.faq.question.758531.html) may help you find the opposite point on the circle, after which the question should be trivial

Comment: Do you know how to find the coordinates of the center of $C$ from its equation?

Answer (score 0):

Complete the squares to find a form of the equation for the circle $C$

from which it is easy to find the coordinates of its center:

$\left(x+\frac32\right)^2+(y+2)^2=r^2$.

Now you have two points on line $L$.

Can you take it from here?